# Java Genrator/Java folder is absent at Intellij 2022.1.2 after installation

Tags: java, intellij-idea

After the installation of Java 17.0.3 and IntelliJ 2022.1.2,
when I create a new project, I don't have the Java folder above the Generator toolbar. According to many video tutorials, it should be created by default.

[Intellij on videos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCp6E.png) - in the red box I've highlighted, you can see Java.

[my Intellij interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuWvi.png) - here is my issue, you can see, that the Java folder is missing in my version of IDEA.

How can I adjust the displaying of this Java folder and create the project on its basis?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's a new interface. Now, language is selected on the right side (Java, Kotlin, etc.)

Comment: I believe my question ain't pretty correct. It isn't about languages, but the Generator toolbar. And the Java folder, which I meant, was above this block of the left bar. Please, look at my picture and in the red box https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCp6E.png , the Java generator or folder exists, but not in my case https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuWvi.png

Comment: Selecting "Java" on the right side will create the same project. Just try it.